# How to put items inside of a sublist?

Tags: python, list, append, sublist

I have this python code for a project to my Intelligent Systems degree:

```
l = [("ola",[[1,2,3],[3,5,6]])]
l[0][1].append[6,7,8]
print(l)
```

When I tried it it keeps giving me this error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

It does not work. I want to append `[6,7,8]` next to `[1,2,3],[3,5,6]`,
so as an output I would want:

```
[("ola",[[1,2,3],[3,5,6],[6,7,8]])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
l[0][1].append([6,7,8])
```

You just forgot the parentheses when calling `append`. The error is telling you that you cannot index ("subscript") the function `append`.

Comment: Thanks!!, it is working, I guess I need to pay more attention.